# ngb Modal make background scrollable

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, angular5

I am searching for away to override the

```
 overflow: hidden
```

style from

```
<body class"modal-open"></body>
```

I am using bootstrap 4 modals.
The background should be scrollable.
Thx

Edit: I tried renderer2 for angular

```
this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(content, options);
this.renderer.removeClass(document.body, 'modal-open');
//this.renderer.removeClass('body', 'modal-open');
//this.renderer.setStyle('body', 'hidden', 'visible');
```

Neither of those options seemed to work

Comment: Did you try to override that property using CSS?

Comment: I gave the modal a custom class and tried tried overflow:visible; but i think the body tag overwrites it

Comment: Did you try to override the body tag's `modal-open` class to change that property instead?

Comment: The thing is i just want to change it for some modals not for all, overwriting it globally will impact all

Comment: Understood, but you will need to change it at the level the CSS property is set at. If you put together a minimal Plunker (or similar) showing what you have, we can advise you on a solution.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel thx for your help if found a "workaround" not beautiful but it works

Comment: Ok. Make sure you document it on here so others who may have the same problem can at least know what you did

Answer (score 0):

I am removing the tag via the renderer therefore use as already mentioned

```
@import {Renderer2} from '@angular/core'
```

inject it in the constructor

```
constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private renderer: Renderer2) { }
```

I assume the class is added sligthly after openModal is called.
Therefore i added an async / await

```
this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(content, options);
        this.modalRef.result.then((result) => {
            this.sendMessage(`${result}`);
        }, (reason) => {
            this.sendMessage(`${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`);
        });
        setTimeout( () =>{
            if(document.body.classList.contains('modal-open')){
                this.renderer.removeClass(document.body, 'modal-open');
                console.log('change');
            }
        }, 100);
```

the class is now properly removed

Answer (score 0):

I opened the modal with the options

```js
NgbModal.open(DialogComponent, {
    backdrop: false,
    windowClass: "no-pointer-events"
})
```

And added this css to my base css file

```css
.no-pointer-events {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Seems to work. I can scroll and interact with the page behind the modal.